# How to configure Bootstrap plugins with Rails + Webpack?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm setting up a new rails project with webpack, but I can't figure it out how to enable Bootstrap plugins (tooltip, alert, etc).

1) Installed dependencies:

```
yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

2) I've required the modules in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
require("popper.js")
require("bootstrap")
```

3) Enabled `$` y `jQuery` in the global scope:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)
```

4) In my views:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip">
  Button
</button>
```

I know JQuery is working, because I can run something like `$('#some-id')` from browser console. But I can't use Bootstrap's plugins. The button doesn't show the tooltip.

If I type `$('#some-id').tooltip()` or `$('#other-id').alert()` I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.alert is not a function

How can I fix this? I've read that I need to importo plugins individually, but it's not working for me:

```
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/alert';
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`Rails 6.0.1`

`config/webpack/enviornment.js`

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

`app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```
import "../stylesheets/application"

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import 'bootstrap/js/src/tooltip'
import 'bootstrap/js/src/alert'

import './main'

window.$ = window.jQuery = $ // make $ available in console for debugging
```

`app/javascript/packs/main.js`

```
// Wait for turbolinks load event
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', () => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  $('.alert').alert()
})
```

`app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss`

```
$primary: #757575;
$light: #e9ecef;

@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'custom.css';
```

to load above stylesheets

`layouts/application.html.erb`.

add `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

or replace `stylesheet_link_tag` with `stylesheet_pack_tag`. if you don't want to use stylesheets in `assets/stylesheets`

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
  var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
  })

  var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
  var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
  })
});
```

import popper.js for B5 is `yarn add @popperjs/core`

Reference: [Bootstrap5 tooltip](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere)

I also face alert issue, i used the bootstrap5 alerts documentation code, then it will worked fine.